# VB - How to print editable line in console

Tags: vb.net, console

In a VB console application, how do you automatically put a string in the cursor? example:

1. ask for numbers
2. user inputs 5 15 five
3. show error
4. show back "5 15 five" back to the user so he can change five to 5 or any other integer.